# Where can I find an online resource for assessing French proficiency or vocabulary?

Tags: vocabulaire, ressources

I sometimes organize French language study group meetups. A serious problem is that people show up a wide spread of competencies. Successful study groups do best when most of the people are at a similar level of (in)competence.

This [vocab test resource](http://testyourvocab.com/) exists for English and would fit the bill if it existed for French.

I'm open to suggestion for other techniques for rapid assessment.

Comment: I didn't know of testyourvocab, thanks for the link =)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Le premier outil qui me vient à l'esprit est [Dialang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIALANG) qui permet de tester le vocabulaire, mais pas uniquement.
C'est un outil de diagnostic basé sur les niveaux du [CECR](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadre_europ%C3%A9en_commun_de_r%C3%A9f%C3%A9rence_pour_les_langues) mais n'est pas un outil de certification.
 Nécessite une connexion à internet et de [s'enregistrer](http://www.lancs.ac.uk/researchenterprise/dialang/about) mais c'est entièrement gratuit.

Je tiens à préciser que ce n'est pas réservé au Français et que les tests sont diponibles dans quatorze langues européennes.

...........

The fist tool that comes to my mind is [Dialang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIALANG). It allows anyone to test his/her language abilities in various competencies, including vocabulary (you can choose which abilities you want to be tested). It is based on the [CEFR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_European_Framework_of_Reference_for_Languages) levels but is not used as a certification tool. One needs to [register](http://www.lancaster.ac.uk/researchenterprise/dialang/DIALANG_PAGE_WebVersion.htm) but use of Dialang is free.

The tests exist for fourteen European languages, not just French.

...........

*Edition*

Une rapide recherche dans les ressources FLE (Français langue étrangère) m'incite à proposer aussi :

- Les [tests](http://www.campus-electronique.tm.fr/TestFle/) du CNED (Centre National d'Enseignement à Distance)
- Le point FLE qui a répertorié des [tests d'évaluation de français en ligne](http://www.lepointdufle.net/tests-de-francais.htm)

Answer (score 3):

Je viens de trouver un outil qui suit exactement le même principe que *testyourvocab*, sans nécessiter la création d'un compte : http://www.abyssum.com/Mesmots/

Il ne procède pas en deux fois et il est donc surement un peu moins précis. On notera aussi qu'il inclut des mots qui n'existent pas pour inciter à répondre honnêtement. Je remarque aussi que les mots n'ont pas été choisis avec [autant de soin](http://testyourvocab.com/details).

S'il s'agit de former des groupes de niveau similaire, il devrait parfaitement remplir cette tâche.